# Looping in a directory to find a folder and delete

Tags: find

I use Dreamweaver to upload the web page to my site, it bring a folder called _note to everywhere in my site. I would like to ask how can I loop in the directory(/home/user/htdocs) to find the folder _note and delete it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a shell on the webserver, this command would do it:

```
find /home/user/htdocs -type d -name _note -exec rm -rfv "{}" \;
```

However I would be more careful then that. I would start by doing this to get a list and make sure its good:

```
find /home/user/htdocs -type d -name _note -exec echo "'{}'" \; > file.txt
```

Then review the file and if its all good:

```
cat file.txt | xargs rm -fvr
```

That way you can catch errors before you delete critical files.

Comment: Very useful of the information, btw what is "{}" in the command line?

Comment: the {} puts each result of the find command in the command you are running with the -exec flag. So in the first example, I search for all directories named _note and then execute the command rm -rfv the directory name. I add quotes, so that if you have a directory like: Files / Folders ... it does not try to remove /.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [lftp](http://lftp.yar.ru/) with `rm -r` to recursively remove a folder/file pattern/name. I think there is command line version of lftp for Windows that you can download and install.